# PHP, pushing array recursively within a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given the following array

```
$a = array(
    'a' => '0',
    'b' => '1',
    'c' => '2',
    'push' => array(
         'd' => '0',
         'e' => '1',
         'here' => array()
    )
);
```

And the following set of loops:

```
// First level
foreach($a as $key=>$value):

     if($key=='push'):

        //Second level
        foreach($value as $key_=>$value_):

             if($key_=='here'):

              // If this key is found then do some stuff here and get another as a result array
              $thirdArray = array(12, 13, 15);

              // Then, I am looking to push this third array from within this loop 
              // Obviously, it should be placed inside this particular key of the array
              // I am trying something like below which doesn't work

              //array_push($value_, $thirdArray);

              endif;

         endforeach;

     endif;

 endforeach;
```

/* The output of printing my array should be

```
  'a' => 'A',
  'b' => 'B',
  'c' => 'C',
      'push' => array(
            'd' => '0',
            'e' => '1',
            'here' => array(

                     array(12, 13, 15)

             )


  */
```

This is giving me a big headache... and can't seem to find a solution.. Many thanks for your help in advance..

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve? Could you clarify some more?

Comment: @user1099862 You need to tell us what your real goal is, not some abstracted version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($value as $key_=>$value_):
  if($key_=='here'):
    $thirdArray = array(12, 13, 15);
    $a['push']['here'][] = $thirdArray;
  endif;
endforeach;
```

or

```
foreach($value as $key_=>$value_):
  if($key_=='here'):
    $thirdArray = array(12, 13, 15);
    $a[$key][$key_][] = $thirdArray;
  endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.. I will keep second option as in the real example i don't know the name of the key..

Answer (score 0):

```
if($key_=='here'):       
    $value[$key_] = array(12, 13, 15);            
endif;
```

Comment: Won't affect the original array, only the copy inside the `foreach` block.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```php
if( isset( $a['push'] ) )
 if( isset( $a['push']['here'] ) )
  $a['push']['here'][] = array(12, 13, 15);
```

would be the fastest way ô.O

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like that:

```
$a[$key][$key_] = array(12, 13, 15);
```

in stead of

```
$thirdArray = array(12, 13, 15);
```

or in case you know the place:

```
$a['push']['here'] = array(12, 13, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could try to do replace `$value` and `$value_` to references, so replace them in the lines 2 and 7 by `&$value` and `&$value_` then you should be able to do what you wanted to (`array_push`)

EDIT: Notice it's not until PHP 5